# Spring bean scopes: session and globalSession

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-ioc

What is the difference between session and globalSession in Spring framework?

```
<bean id="exampleBean" class="com.test.baen.ExampleBean" scope="session"/>
<bean id="exampleBean" class="com.test.baen.ExampleBean" scope="globalSession"/>
```

As per my study, both are valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

Now, session bean scope will remain until the user session, but will globalSession bean scope be available throughout the whole application?

**Is it the application scope?**

I am unable to understand the term "global HTTP Session"; will it be available throughout the global HTTP Session?

Comment: If you got here - globalSession has been removed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54742157/were-globalsession-scoped-beans-removed-from-spring-5-why/54742361#54742361

Answer (score 121, accepted):

`globalSession` is something that is connected to Portlet applications. When your application works in a Portlet container it is built of some amount of portlets. Each portlet has its own session, but if you want to store variables global for all portlets in your application then you should store them in `globalSession`. This scope doesn't have any special effect different from the `session` scope in Servlet based applications.

Comment: globalSession sounds a lot like the default singleton. What would be the main difference between them?

Comment: after 20 minutes of sifting through answers on here and other sites, finally someone links it to portlets and their global session. Now it is clear

Answer (score 17):

As per Spring documentation ::

session - Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of an HTTP Session. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

global session - Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a global HTTP Session. Typically only valid when used in a portlet context. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 1):

Session scope adds bean definiton of a http session, valid only in application context. a new bean will be created for each http session by the conntainer.
Global session scope adds bean definiton of a global http session used in portlet application context.