# Were GlobalSession scoped beans removed from spring 5? Why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**1. Were global-session scoped beans removed from Spring 5?**

Official documentation no longer mentions it.
SCOPE_GLOBAL_SESSION is no longer part of RequestAttributes:

Spring 4: https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestAttributes.html#SCOPE_GLOBAL_SESSION

Spring 5: https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestAttributes.html#SCOPE_GLOBAL_SESSION

**2. If 1 is true: why were they removed?**

**Update:**

Found a commit that removes the stuff. Seems it is because of dropping of Portlet:
See commit : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/2b3445df8134e2b0c4e4a4c4136cbaf9d58b7fc4#diff-42e7410c98a33ab499e5c27858b1c985

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. That `SCOPE_GLOBAL_SESSION` is for sharing session across Portlets and Servlets. And Portlet supported is removed in Spring 5 in [SPR-14129](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18701) because of  :

> Spring's Portlet MVC support turned into a second-class feature in
>   recent years, never having been updated to the modern-day
>   `HandlerMethod` infrastructure that Servlet MVC is based on these days
>   (since 3.1 already, with the old Servlet MVC variant deprecated since
>   3.2). Furthermore, the Portlet 3.0 specification intends to introduce annotation-driven dispatching itself, so there is no strategic place
>   for Spring Portlet MVC either, even within its present niche. And last
>   but not least, common Portlet environments seem to be stuck on Spring
>   3.x, not even upgrading to Spring 4.x yet.
>
> We will therefore drop Portlet MVC support completely as of Spring 5,
>   while at the same time introducing our Reactive MVC variant. We intend
>   to keep supporting (but not recommending) the use of Spring with JSF
>   in a Portlet environment, in particular through Spring Web Flow. For
>   all other purposes, Spring Framework 4.3.x will remain supported until
>   2020, including its Portlet MVC support (and underlying Servlet 2.5
>   support).

Comment: This is correct. Found commit : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/2b3445df8134e2b0c4e4a4c4136cbaf9d58b7fc4#diff-42e7410c98a33ab499e5c27858b1c985